# I need to copy rows with matching zips to their corresponding sheets

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see in the image I have a column with zip codes and sheets that match up. I need to have all of the zip codes that match a sheet copied over, another issue is that some sheets are made up of two or more zip codes. I know I can do this with an incredible amount of If statements nested in a Do Until but I feel like that is a very inefficient way to do this. I am still learning so I was hoping someone might be able to help out. Thanks in advance.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: Use Microsoft Query on each Worksheet in Excel

Create on each worksheet a quick MS Query like the one below.

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ZIP = "94585"
```

In case you need more than 1 ZIP code:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ZIP = "94585" OR ZIP = "94586"
```

How to create Microsoft Queries in Excel? Go to `Data->From Other Sources->Microsoft Query` or use my AddIn: [link here](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/).

[image: Using Microsoft Query to get subset of Zip records]

### Option 2: VBA Macro

Create a VBA macro that:

1. Traverses across the Worksheets
2. Checks the ZIP code in the name of the Worksheet (i am guessing this is how it's organized)
3. Traverses all rows in `Sheet1` and copies the row if it matches the ZIP(s)

Some code stubs below:

**Traversing worksheets**

```
for each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
  'Your code here
Next ws
```

**Traverse rows and check if matching zip(s)**

```
  for i = 1 to i = (ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row-1)
  if Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = ZIP1 or Range("A1").Offset(i).Value = ZIP2 then
    'Copy the row
  end if
Next ws
'ws - is Sheet1
```

Comment: I feel like option one is much more simple! Will that take the entire row with it though? I need the whole entry.

Comment: Sure if will take all columns if you use `SELECT *` or it can take just some columns if you name them like `SELECT Address, ZIP`. See my post just to learn more on how to use Microsoft Queries in Excel: http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/

Comment: Would appreciate the +1 if this proved helpful

Comment: I could not get the first option to work. The second is basically how I planned to do it origanly but the amount of code to do this is quite large. There are roughly 40 zips that I will need to filter through. It may be my only option though

Comment: Checkout my updated post. I included a screenshot using my AddIn. You may just as well use Data->From other...->Microsoft Query

Comment: I see how that would work well but im not sure how you are able to compare to "ZIP" how do you label your columns like that? furthermore I need to be able to automate the process so a coworker can use this file.

Comment: The label is simply the value of the first cell in the column of your Sheet1 worksheet. That's how Microsoft Query works. The labels should be in row #1. Anyone can use the file as it is a standard MS Query. The AddIn is just to make it easier to create the queries - its open source anyway in VBA